# Android Restoring order of fragments in the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I got 2 activities, A and B. Each activity is a container for fragments which are replaced with a `FragmentTransaction`.

I got an issue on some devices that when a user opens Activity B while he was in Activity A, the first activity is probably destroyed, which means that when a user clicks the back button, it makes the first activity recreated while in a normal device, it would just resume.

My main issue is that the user loses its fragment stack he had in the first activity. When the user opened the 2nd activity, he was already 3 fragments "deep" the first activity. How can I restore the stack and return the user to the point he's been before the first activity was destroyed?

Comment: you can search for setRetainInstance(true) to get some solution about restoring order of fragment

Comment: Can you make sure, that the `Bundle` that is being passed to the `onCreate()` method as a parameter is not `null` when user moves back from `ActivityB`? Also please post `onCreate()` implementation of your `ActivityA()`.

Comment: @azizbekian yes I can. For now I use this method to replace the fragment to the main fragment of the app, but usually its not the one he was in before opening the 2nd activity.

Comment: @YonatanNir, I think you should do nothing if `savedInstanceState != null`. In that case `FragmentManager` will take care of restoring the state appropriately.

Comment: @azizbekian if I do nothing, then the "first" fragment of the application is displayed which is supposed to be displayed only when the user first opens the app.

Comment: That's interesting. Bookmarking this in order to see what the issue was.

Comment: @azizbekian there's nothing special with it.. it's just the flow of the app - when the activity is created it loads the first fragment. Since in this case it is recreatred, then again it reaches the code where it loads the first fragment.

Comment: As long as activity is recreated (not created for first time), `FragmentManager` will take care of restoring previous state, which currently does not happen. That's what I call *"interesting"*.

Comment: @azizbekian it may be doing it, but my code specifically loads the first fragment. It seems like you might think of a situation where the activity is only resumed and not recreated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be handled by the Android OS automatically. You can turn developer option "don't keep activities" on to always mimic this behavior (destroying your activity) when your activity goes to the background. After that you can start debugging. Some things to check:

- In onCreate of the activity, are you calling the super onCreate with
  the savedInstanceState?
- If you put a breakpoint at the start of onCreate, when you "come
  back" to the activity, is there a saved instance state?
- Where are you creating the fragments? Are you re-creating them
  manually (you shouldn't)?
- Are your fragments hardcoded in the layout or replaced in the layout
  (replacing a container view)?

*** EDIT ***

From your reply I derive that this is the problem, you say: "In the end of the onCreate I am replacing the fragment with a fragment transaction and thus load the first fragment of the app" => you should not do that when the savedInstanceState is not null. Otherwise you're destroying what is already there from the saved state.

Check here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Notice the return when savedInstanceState is not null.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describes sounds like a case where the first activity is resumed without being destroyed before that. 
onCreate does call the super. If the activity is destroyed and I come back, the saved instance is not null. In the end of the onCreate I am replacing the fragment with a fragment transaction and thus load the first fragment of the app. I am replacing them in a container view.

Comment: "In the end of the onCreate I am replacing the fragment with a fragment transaction and thus load the first fragment of the app" => you should not do that when the savedInstanceState is not null. Otherwise you're destroying what is already there from the saved state. Check here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: OK I have created the first fragments only when the savedinstance was null and it seems to work